# Discours rapporté indirect et concordance des temps

Tags: grammaire, concordance-des-temps, discours-indirect

Pour moi la règle est plutôt simple (voir https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-7931.php).

Mais c'est vrai que j'y entends souvent des entorses. Par conséquent je suis un peu confus car je ne sais pas s'il y a des exceptions (tout porte à croire que oui).

Je viens de tomber sur l'exemple suivant:

> Béchir Saleh : "Abdallah Senoussi **a dit** qu’il **donne** de l’argent à Sarkozy."

source : https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/france/financement-libyen-b%C3%A9chir-saleh-charge-nicolas-sarkozy/ar-AAxFwST?li=BBoJIji

C'est clairement un discours indirect, je me trompe?
Pourquoi le verbe **donner** n'est pas à l'imparfait (ou plus-que-parfait?) ?

Comment: Pour moi, c'est pour mettre en avant le côté "présent" de l'action; si tu dis "qu'il donnait de l'argent", on peut comprendre cet imparfait avec un passé composé "qu'il a donné de l'argent" --> action résolue.

Comment: @Nathan à ce titre, on pourrait dire : `Il faut absolument qu'il fera ça demain` :)

Comment: @smarber C'est un très mauvais exemple car falloir est un verbe impersonnel: Il faudra absolument qu'il fasse ça demain
Pour répondre à ta question, donner est au présent pour montrer qu'il donnait et qu'il continue de donner.

Comment: @Ckankonmange `J'exige qu'il fera ça demain` :D. Je suis d'accord avec l'explication disant que c'est pour souligner la continuité de l'action (ce qui n'est pas possible au passage mais soit). Ce que je ne comprends pas est pourquoi ça ne respecte pas la règle? De quelle exception s'agit-il?

Answer (score 2):

Plusieurs possibilités sont envisageables :

1. Soit il continue de donner de l’argent, dans ce cas pas de problème.
2. Soit, étant donné que c’est un locuteur libyen, il a fait une faute en parlant, le français n’étant pas sa langue première.
3. Soit l’article rapporte mal les propos exacts, ce qui est courant dans les articles relayés sur internet par des agrégateurs comme MSN.

Comment: Pourquoi l'hypothèse numéro 1 ne respecte pas la règle que j'ai cité dans ma question? (le présent devient de l'imparfait, le futur du conditionnel etc ...)